# Dual citizen, British and Malaysian. Going through a neutral country might be better. Why?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality, malaysian-citizens

I am a dual citizen, Britain and Malaysian. Right now I am in Malaysia. I will be doing my university degree in the Netherlands this September, and will be away for 3 years.

Can I leave Malaysia, showing my Malaysian passport at immigration, fly to the Netherlands, and at the Netherlands immigration produce my UK passport (because I don't need a student visa and getting a job is much easier)? Then after three years, when I leave the Netherlands, show my British passport there, and at immigration into Malaysia produce my Malaysian passport.

Will there be a problem? Will Malaysia be suspicious of something because I was in the Netherlands for 3 years? I don't want to lose both my citizenships and I don't want Malaysia to find out.

In the question [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel) I read that going through a neutral country might be better.

Note: Malaysia doesn't allow its citizens to also hold other citizenships. If Malaysia finds out that I have a British passport, I will have to cancel one citizenship.

Comment: I take it from your question that Malaysia doesn't allow its citizens also to hold other citizenships?

Comment: @madhatter you take it correctly

Comment: I think this is better at expatriates.stackexchange.com. For a short stay a third country may easily give you a visa, so you enter that country with your Malaysian passport, get entry stamp, exit towards UK/EU with your UK passport. To return you do the opposite, enter with UK/EU passport and leave towards Malaysia with your Malaysia passport, you get entry and exit stamps in your Malaysian that justify all of your absence. But getting a visa in another country for three years is a more complicated issue.

Comment: @JanDoggen (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: @SJuan76 yeah 3 years is pretty long. But I don't know what to do. I really want to keep both citizenship and go to ned with UK passport as I can get cheaper university tuition fees.

Comment: @JanDoggen if Malaysia finds out that I have a british passport, I will have to cancel one citizenship, but I want to try my best not to cancel both citizenships. Not illegal! I am going for my studies i just dont want hassle middle of my semester i get a call saying to go back to malaysia or chose which citizenship to revoke.

Comment: I will show my malaysian passport to the malaysian immigration in malaysia from netherlands. British passport will be shown to Ned's immigration desk when leaving Ned.

Comment: @casey-campbell Having a UK passport does not entitle you to home fees. Fees are based on residency. This passport shuffle will be pointless.

Comment: I'd rather think that Malaysia would be suspicious that you were in The Netherlands for three years without a visa or other permission. That's a long time.

Comment: @CaseyCampbell actually havin two citizenships is illegal in Malaysia. Unfortunate but true... The only way for you to prevent any enquiries from Malaysia authorities is to apply for a student visa on your Malaysian passport.

Comment: @TomJin okay but it will still be easier for me to get a job in Europe with British passport,as compared to a Malaysian passport